# Is Java EE exe available with Eclipse IDE

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms

I am new to java world.

I am trying to run a jms application eg. given at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/client.html#1027256

In sections 4.3.3 and 4.3.4 he is asking to run Java EE and j2eeadmin commands. I got "Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers"  but could not find the above exe's  in eclipse folder.

Do I need to seperately download Java EE libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Praveen

Comment: Note that Java EE 1.3 is pretty old - Java EE6 is current. Save yourself some hassle by directly starting with EE6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to download from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html .  The Eclipse "Java EE IDE for Web Developers" contains additional tools (plugins) for working with Java EE features, but doesn't actually contain the Java EE distribution.

Additional required setup to make proper use of these tools once installed is documented at the top of the same page you linked to, at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/jms/tutorial/1_3_1-fcs/doc/client.html#1025256.

Comment: I installed "Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 Web Profile SDK Update 3 (with JDK 6u29)" but j2ee or j2eeadmin are not present in the installation source.                                                    I read that full profile would have j2ee administratoin too. But there is no clearly mentioned @http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html as to which one is a full profile download. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks, Praveen